# How to pre-fill UserVoice dialog with a specific value?

Tags: javascript, uservoice

I'm using UserVoice for our site and when someone clicks on some button in my page, I want to pop up a UserVoice dialog, which is already embedded in my site. I know I can do it with the `UserVoice.showPopupWidget();` function.

The problem is that I want to prefill some value into this dialog such as email, title, content... But I can't figure out how to do this. I read the UserVoice code and see that the `Widget` object might do this, but I can't access this object.

Can anyone here please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Uservoice use iframe to "pop" its form up, so unless it is supported in their API, no way you can do that

Comment: Yes, but I think there's a mechanism to pass parameter to UserVoice. I can do this with email field, but still got stuck with Content field and Subject field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find info on passing info into the widget here: http://feedback.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/225-pass-custom-data-through-the-widget-and-into-the-h

Unfortunately you cannot pass subject.

Hope that helps!